# How to remove markers cluster from google map(Ionic4)

Tags: ionic-framework, markerclusterer

How to remove markers cluster from google map(Ionic4)

part codes flow:

import * as MarkerClusterer from 'node-js-marker-clusterer';

markerCluster: MarkerClusterer;

```
        if (this.markerCluster) {
          this.markerCluster.clearMarkers();
        }


        this.markerCluster = this.map.addMarkerClusterSync({
          markers: this.locations,
          boundsDraw: false,
          icons: [
            {min: 2, max: 100, url: "./assets/icon/favicon.ico", anchor: 
          {x: 16, y: 16}}
          ]
        });
```

this.markerCluster.clearMarkers();   ←this code not work

Answer (score 0):

this is the simple way to remove all marker on google map,

```
this.map.clear();
```

this simple example found in [githup](https://github.com/mapsplugin/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo-v4/blob/master/src/app/home/home.page.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ToastController,
  Platform,
  LoadingController
} from '@ionic/angular';
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  Marker,
  GoogleMapsAnimation,
  MyLocation
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  map: GoogleMap;
  loading: any;

  constructor(
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private platform: Platform) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    // Since ngOnInit() is executed before `deviceready` event,
    // you have to wait the event.
    await this.platform.ready();
    await this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741704,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    });

  }

  async onButtonClick() {
    this.map.clear();

    this.loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Please wait...'
    });
    await this.loading.present();

    // Get the location of you
    this.map.getMyLocation().then((location: MyLocation) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(location, null ,2));

      // Move the map camera to the location with animation
      this.map.animateCamera({
        target: location.latLng,
        zoom: 17,
        tilt: 30
      });

      // add a marker
      let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
        title: '@ionic-native/google-maps plugin!',
        snippet: 'This plugin is awesome!',
        position: location.latLng,
        animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.BOUNCE
      });

      // show the infoWindow
      marker.showInfoWindow();

      // If clicked it, display the alert
      marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
        this.showToast('clicked!');
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.showToast(err.error_message);
    });
  }

  async showToast(message: string) {
    let toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: message,
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'middle'
    });

    toast.present();
  }
}
```